# How to Multiple checkbox post unchecked post 0 value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, codeigniter

I have multiple of checkbox within a form  that are saved in a loop after submission. The problem is when there are unchecked checkbox then I can't get the post value. I know if I want to get 0 value so create hidden input with same name and set value to 0, but this is multiple checkbox.
Here is my code:

```html
<div class="col-4">
  <label class="switch switch-lg">
    <input type="checkbox" name="order[1]" id="order-1">
    <input type="hidden" id="hd-check-1" name="order[1]" value="0">
    
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <label class="switch switch-lg">
        <input type="checkbox" name="order[2]" id="order-2">
        <input type="hidden" id="hd-check-2" name="order[2]" value="0">
        
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
          <label class="switch switch-lg">
            <input type="checkbox" name="order[3]" id="order-3">
            <input type="hidden" id="hd-check-3" name="order[3]" value="0">

            </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 3;
  
  for (i = 1, j = 1; i <= count, j <= count; i++, j++) {
    var check = $('#order-' + i + '');
    var hidden = $('#hd-check-' + j + '');
    
    check.on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        $(this).val(1);
        hidden.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        console.log('ck: ', ck);
      } 
      else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
        hidden.removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).val(0);
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Above code if I checked the checkbox not effected the hidden input. Any idea how to solve this? That I want is when the checkbox not checked and I submit the form I want to get the value.
Thanks for advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to get unchecked post value?

Comment: Yes, I need uncheck value for insert to database.

Comment: I'll will do checking with PHP, and i treat it as uncheck if no value, less hassle

Comment: I already checking with php, but how to change null value become 0? as you know this is loop checkbox.

Comment: yupss, I get it. I can solve this. Thanks, you save my day.

Comment: you didn't close your label tags...

Comment: And why do you have to count vars in the for loop? You can define the ``hidden`` var also with ``i``...